# How to set badge in NavigationView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-navigationview

I use `NavigationDrawer` from desin lib

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

There is `XML`

```
....

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_second"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_third_drawer" />

....
```

There is point where i am setting menu

```
app:menu="@menu/activity_third_drawer"
```

There is `XML` of menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_inbox"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_mail_outline_white"
        android:title="@string/inbox" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
        android:title="@string/gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
        android:title="@string/slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
        android:title="@string/tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="@string/about_app">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
            android:title="@string/about1" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Eventually it is looks like this

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

but I need when message is caming to inbox it should be marked in `NavigationDrawer`.

Like this

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

There are a lot of deffirent libs that can help with this issue, I chose [this one](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger).

This lib can attach badge wherever you want, but there are no one sample hoe to attach it to `<item>` . The closest sample is how to attach to `XML`

```
<com.readystatesoftware.viewbadger.BadgeView
            android:id="@+id/badge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="OK" />
```

but i still can't think out how to attach it to `<item>`

Maybe there are another solution how to make it?

I have tryed this way

```
View menuItemView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_inbox));
    BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(context, menuItemView);
    badge.setText("1");
    badge.show();
```

but every time I get `menuItemView = null`

then I have tried this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    View menuItemView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.nav_inbox));
    BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(context, menuItemView);
    badge.setText("1");
    badge.show();

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

but it is the same `menuItemView = null`:

Debag

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

My `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_second"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_third_drawer" />
```

My `menu`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_inbox"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox_checked"
        android:title="Inbox"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/badge" />

</group>

<item android:title="@string/about_app">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_24dp"
            android:title="@string/about1" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

My `badge`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textMenuItemCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="rrrr"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:alpha="0.6"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    MenuItem item = navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_inbox);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.badge);
    RelativeLayout notifCount = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    TextView tv = (TextView) notifCount.findViewById(R.id.textMenuItemCount);

    String count = "4";
    if (count != null) {
        tv.setText(count);
    }else{
        tv.setText("");
        item.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

This is screenshot debag

[image]

This is what I get finally

[image]

it is nothing, but according debug mode all is ok, without any error, but I can't see any badge.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Eventually i use this lib https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Answer (score 5):

use custom layout for menu items.

activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/rv_venues"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:gravity="right|end"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="false">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/btnSearchVenues"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_overlay"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/btnSort"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_overlay"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_filter"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/btnMap"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_btn_overlay"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_map"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/poweredBy"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#793f6edc" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" >
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_search"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pin_map"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            app:fabSize="normal"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

menu_drawer.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <group android:id="@+id/group_settings_id0">
        <item android:title="@string/btnFriends"
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_friends"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/navlist"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_circles"/>

        <item android:title="@string/btnPhotos"
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_photos"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/navlist"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"/>

        <item android:title="@string/btnCheckins"
            android:id="@+id/nav_item_checkins"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/navlist"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location"/>
        </group>

        <group android:id="@+id/group_settings_id1">
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_find_people"
                android:title="@string/action_find_people"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"/>
        </group>

        <group android:id="@+id/group_settings_id2">
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_about"
                android:title="@string/action_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_info"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_help"
                android:title="@string/action_help"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_logout"
                android:title="@string/action_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_exit"/>
        </group>
   </menu>
```

badge.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="center">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMenuItemCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:alpha="0.6"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in your Activity:

in onCreate method:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);


mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name,
        R.string.app_name) {

    /**
     * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
     */
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        fab.show();
    }

    /**
     * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
     */
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        fab.hide();
    }
};

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

//call whenever you want to update the badge

```
public void updateNavView(NavigationView navView, int resId, String count){
    MenuItem item = navView.getMenu().findItem(resId); //ex. R.id.nav_item_friends
        //MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.badge);
        RelativeLayout notifCount = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        TextView tv = (TextView) notifCount.findViewById(R.id.textMenuItemCount);

        if (count != null) {
            tv.setText(count);
        }else{
            tv.setText("");
            item.setEnabled(false);
        }
}
```

and the result is 
[image]

Comment: Finally it doesn't work for me((

Comment: Did you try my code and what result or error did u get?

Comment: Yes i tryed your code, i add edit in question... What i am doing wrong? Maybe if you have code example in some project ?

Comment: Maybe should i someway set `visibility`?

Comment: Could you please edit your anser for full badge.xml layout file with RelativeLayout? And also edit your actiivty-codesnippet to specify, which methods contain which code (e.g. onCreate for init, onResume for refresh of badge)? Also, you are setting the actionView in XML and in code, which shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: @arne.jans u re correct! no need for setActionView again it should work without it. i put updateNavView method so when the badge count changes, fire an event to call this method. (i.e. with custom listener or broadcastreceiver)

Comment: Thank you for updating! Also, I noticed you use actionLayout-attribute within android-namespace. I think it should be used with the app-namespace to be used correctly on older android-version.