# How to add a notification badge in a list item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-notifications

Could I get some pointers around Notification Badges?

I'm needing to create a notification badge with count on a list item in a recyclerView. I'm needing to add the badge at the end of the list item.

All I could find on here is how a badge could be added on a corner of on icon or button or bottom navigation or tabs using BadgeDrawable and BadgeUtil.

At this point I'm thinking of creating a button that's invisible and add the badge at the top corner. But with that approach I won't be able to place the badge in the center.

I could also go with a circle and add text inside but I'm struggling with that idea because how would it adapt to the count size?

Any thought would be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you please show in image how you want to show badge? Without any pictured it's hard to give any solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set badge in NavigationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293451/how-to-set-badge-in-navigationview)